# Hashmap, can't modify/update

Tags: java, hashmap, updates

Just learned about hashmap recently.  So far, my code can Add, Remove, print performance scales, and sort last/first Names of an Employee.  However, update/modify is not doing anything.  My attempt is, to first search for an Employee's ID that I want to update.  After entering their ID, I would then prompt the user to modify a performance scale, but afterwards if the user prints out all Performance Scale, it still does not change anything.

Therefore, any advice/tips/links on how to update is helpful.  Here's some part of my code that covers all cases. (Case 3 is the update/modify, shows my attempted work on it).

```
switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            addEmployee(firstAndLast, idNumber, performanceScale);
            break;
        case 2:
            removeEmployee(firstAndLast, idNumber, performanceScale);
            break;

        case 3:
            modifyPerformanceScale(idNumber);
            break;
        case 4:
            printAllperfScale(performanceScale);
            break;
        case 5:
            printLastNameAscending(firstAndLast);
            break;
        case 6:
            exit = true;
            System.out.println("Exiting program...");
            break;
        default:
            System.out
                    .println("Please choose a number from 1 - 5 from the menu.");
        }
    }

}

public static void addEmployee(TreeMap<String, Employee> firstAndLastMap,
        TreeMap<Integer, Employee> idNumberMap,
        TreeMap<Employee, Integer> performanceScale) {
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int id;
    int perfScale;

    System.out.print("Enter first name for the Employee: ");
    firstName = keyboardInput.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter last name for the Employeer: ");
    lastName = keyboardInput.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter ID number of the Employee: ");
    id = keyboardInput.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Performance Scale rating between 1 to 5: ");
    perfScale = keyboardInput.nextInt();

    Employee addEmployee = new Employee(lastName, firstName, id, perfScale);

    firstAndLastMap.put(lastName + ", " + firstName, addEmployee);
    idNumberMap.put(id, addEmployee);

    performanceScale.put(addEmployee, perfScale);

}

public static void removeEmployee(TreeMap<String, Employee> firstAndLastMap,
        TreeMap<Integer, Employee> idNumberMap,
        TreeMap<Employee, Integer> performanceScale) {

    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int id;
    System.out.print("Enter First name of Employee you want to remove: ");
    firstName = keyboardInput.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter last name of Employee you want to remove: ");
    lastName = keyboardInput.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter ID number of Employee you want to remove: ");
    id = keyboardInput.nextInt();



    firstAndLastMap.remove(lastName + ", " + firstName);
    idNumberMap.remove(id); 


}

public static void modifyPerformanceScale(TreeMap<Integer, Employee> idNumber) {
    System.out.print("Enter ID: ");
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    int idNumber1;
    int modScale;
    idNumber1 = keyboardInput.nextInt();
    idNumber.remove(idNumber1);

    System.out.print("Enter the number you want to change to: ");
    modScale = keyboardInput.nextInt();
}

public static void printAllperfScale(TreeMap<Employee,Integer> performanceScale) {
    Set Employee1 = performanceScale.entrySet();    
    Iterator itr1 = Employee1.iterator();

    while (itr1.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) itr1.next();
        System.out.println(me.getValue());
    }
}


public static void printLastNameAscending(TreeMap<String, Employee> LastName) {
    Set Employee1 = LastName.entrySet();
    Iterator itr1 = Employee1.iterator();

    while (itr1.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) itr1.next();
        System.out.println(me.getKey());
    }
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to change your method to

```
public static void modifyPerformanceScale(TreeMap<Integer, Employee> idNumber, TreeMap<Employee, Integer> performanceScale) {
    System.out.print("Enter ID: ");
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    int idNumber1;
    int modScale;
    idNumber1 = keyboardInput.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the number you want to change to: ");
    modScale = keyboardInput.nextInt();

    Employee employee = idNumber.get(idNumber1); //note: This will return null if the employee does not exist. Check for this, if necessary.
    performanceScale.put(employee, modScale);
}
```

This gets the employee with that id.

This replaces the previous entry for that employee with the new entry. (`Map.put` adds the entry if the key does not exist, or it replaces the entry for that key if it already exists in the map.)

And then make sure to pass in the correct `TreeMap`s to your new `modifyPerformanceScale` method.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply sir.  I will do as you ask, and make sure i understand the reason for the code. :)  After a few mins, i'll click on the checkmark.

Comment: I noticed a bug and fixed it. Be sure to use the edited answer.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for your contribution. :) appreciate the help.